# How to do unit and integration tests on AMP Ads?

Tags: amp-html

I'm developing AMP Ads project in my work.(for add a new Ad network)

I did change code in local and I could confirmed to show sample Ad in examples page with 'gulp' command.

But I don't know the test process.

The explanation of [GitHub](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/tree/master/3p#ads) has 2 step.

- Provide unit and integration tests.
- Provide test accounts for inclusion in our open source repository for integration tests.

What does it mean?
How to do unit and integration tests on AMP Ads?

Should I contact to Google team or somethings?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to test an AMP document. IME, here is the easiest method. Append your `<origin-domain>/<path>` as shown below:

```
https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/<origin-domain>/<path>
```

Note that the /s portion is optional and signals a secure origin, so if the origin isn't served over https, then you would use:

```
https://cdn.ampproject.org/c/<origin-domain>/<path>
```

This approach will test all AMP elements, including `<amp-ad>`. If you have an error, the error message will point to the line in your file with the error (conveniently, it does not reformat the file and force you to look for the formatted file line number, as some validators do).

The best practices cited on the above page should be followed (e.g. HTTPS). One reason is that the CDN validator may not flag some of the practices identified on the above page. If you use iframe, be careful to follow the Google proximity-to-page-top rules; these require you to manually measure the location of the iframe relative to page-top. IME this can be tedious.

Comment: Hi Jay. Thank you for comment. I want to add a new Ad network. Is it test to confirm whether Google CDN has been properly cache?

Comment: Would you add detail to your comment? I am not sure what you are asking. For example, are you testing Analytics for an Ad, or a new Analytics provider? I need more information to be able to suggest a solution.

Comment: I'm sorry to take the time. I'm thinking that send pull request as supported 3rd party like A9 or GMOSSP([#2814](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/2814)) or Yahoo! Japan([#3285](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/3285)). I want to know how to do unit and integration test that conforming to the Terms.